# choosing document to be printed by PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().print

Tags: java, awt

This code snippet is given as an example for using a print dialog in oracle java tutorials:

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    if (pj.printDialog())
    {
        try {
            pj.print();
            }
        catch (PrinterException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
         }
     }
```

I didn't understand where is the process of selecting what to print happening? Where should I specify which document is to be printed?

Comment: That would depend.  What are you printing?  There are at least three ways you can print something in Java.

Comment: I want to allow a user to print pdf documents by providing a print dialog. I don't know what input should I give for printing, the file handle or file path and also where to give this input.